# C# replacing huge if-else statement

Tags: c#, design-patterns

let's say i have Item object witch mostly holds enum properties like this

```
public enum Shape
{
    square = 1,
    trangle = 2,
    any = 3
}

public enum Color
{
    blue = 1,
    red = 2,
    yellow = 3,
    green = 4
}


public enum Material
{
    glass = 1,
    wood = 2,
    metal = 3
}


public class Item
{
    public Shape ItemShape { get; set; }
    public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
    public Material ItemMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

What am trying to do is depends of combination of whole  three  properties  i need to do some action later;

I was thinking to use if-else combination like:

```
if(item.ItemShape == Shape.square && item.ItemColor == Color.blue && item.ItemMaterial == Material.glass)
        {
            //call Action1
        }
        else if(item.ItemShape == Shape.square && item.ItemColor == Color.blue && item.ItemMaterial == Material.wood)
        {
            // action2
        }
        ......
```

Problem is that i have around 16 of combinations, so it will be huge if-else method to resolve what method should i call later.

[image]

Maybe is there  any other way to replace if-else statements more  readable code, design patter or something more efficient?

I was thinking to combine whole possible states as flag enum values, but not sure if  i can create enum value from object property later.

Comment: You can use a dictionary, i.e. define `var actions = new Dictionary<Item, Action> { [new Item(Shape.Square, Color.Blue, Material.Glass)] = Action1, [new Item(Shape.Square, Color.Blue, Material.Wood)] = Action2, … };` (for the sake of brevity I assume a constructor to set the values) somewhere in your class and then just call the appropriate action with the one-liner `if actions.TryGetValue(item, out var action) { action(); }` instead of your if-else-block.

Comment: The Dictionary approach isn't going to work directly for the 'Any' case: you would need to add each variant into the dictionary.

Comment: I was going to suggest a custom attribute on each method configured with the shape, color, and material types. The dictionary approach seems more reasonable and avoids reflection.

Comment: @IanMercer, `Shape.Any=3` is a specific value on the enum, not a generalization like any parameter

Comment: @mat1c is 'Any' the same as 'any'? Will there be rules where not all the values are specified?

Comment: @ckuri, `Item` is a class, so by default reference equality will be used, so it is not a good candidate for `Dictionary` key - if we do not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` - that is how my answer different from your solution, please let me know if you disagree

Comment: @ironstone13 I agree, but I think the simplest solution would be to just make `Item` a struct.

Comment: @ckuri, I completely agree with you that is why I wrote in my answer that `Item` should be a struct, from the very beginning. However, equality for structs is implemented in `System.ValueType` and is usually slower then your custom implementation :-)

Comment: @mat1c - I've added one more alternative design in my answer (with state like pattern), please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet would be to ceate a `Dictionary` that would map your values to methods.
Now there are several options what could be the key in your dictionary - see below.

**Disclaimer**
Please also note that a big if statement is only an issue, if it is spread / duplicated across the codebase, and changes frequently - putting things in a dictionary *does not really reduce complexity*. Having methods in a dictionary also changes the semantics of your code. The first question should be - am *I changing the mappings at runtime? Should they really be dynamic?*

1. `Dictionary` with key `ValueTuple` struct you could use syntax `(Shape, Color, Material)` - this is the easiest one. *Please note* - **not** the `Tuple` class, but `ValueTuple` struct.
2. `Dictionary` with key `Item` class itself, but then you would need to **take care about proper equality comparison** in `Item`. You could make `Item` a **struct** to get that for free (but with slower performance, that comes from equality comparisons in `System.ValueType` that uses reflection in general case), or leave it as a class (or struct) and implement `IEquatable<Item>`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.
   *Without proper equality comparison, your dictionary lookup will not work (as suggested by @ckuri)*
3. Use `ValueTuple` without a dictionary to simply condense your code.
4. A *variation* of the [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) where you have a shared interface / base class for your handler. Handler is a separate class that contains one action for a specific set of values, like `AnyBlueGlassHandler : Handler`. Each handler checks the `If` condition, and when true, runs the actions. You could then put the handlers in a `List<T>` and apply them for an item like `handlers.Foreach(x=>x.Handle(item))`

The code when `Item` is the key could look like:

```
    public static class ItemExtensions
    {
    static Dictionary<Item, Action<Item>>
        methods = new Dictionary<Item, Action<Item>>()
        {
            { new Item(Shape.any, Color.blue, Material.glass), x=> { /*do something*/ } }
        };


    public static bool TryApply(this Item item)
    {
        if (methods.TryGetValue(item, out var action))
        {
            action(item);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

the code when `ValueTuple` is the key could look like

```
 public static class ItemExtensionsUsingValueTuple
 {
    static Dictionary<(Shape, Color, Material), Action<Item>>
        methods = new Dictionary<(Shape, Color, Material), Action<Item>>()
        {
            { (Shape.any, Color.blue, Material.glass), x=> { /*do something*/ } }
        };


    public static bool TryApply(this Item item)
    {
        if (methods.TryGetValue((item.ItemShape, item.ItemColor, item.ItemMaterial), out var action))
        {
            action(item);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

a more condensed version of your code with ifs, could look like:

- declare Key property on your Item class
  `public (Shape, Color, Material) Key => (ItemShape, ItemColor, ItemMaterial);`
- use more elegant if statement
  `if ( item.Key == (Shape.any, Color.blue, Material.glass)) { }`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want some rule set to check an item against. 
I think the simplest form to make this more readable, is to pass the item, the properties of the rule, and the action to a separate method:

```
    public bool RunActionIf(Item item, Shape shape, Color color, Material material, Action action)
    {
        if(item.ItemShape == shape && item.ItemColor == color && item.ItemMaterial == material)
        {
            action();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void RunAction(Item item)
    {
        var result =
            RunActionIf(item, Shape.square, Color.blue, Material.glass, Action1) ||
            RunActionIf(item, Shape.square, Color.blue, Material.wood, Action2) ||
            /* Implement your whole table like this */;

        if(!result)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No matching rule found", nameof(item));
        }
    }
```

The main advantage of that method is that it's shorter and with less 'overhead' in the declaration. You can easily see: shape X + color Y + material Z= that action.

Another advantage is that it's easier to implement certain exceptions, for instance by allowing one of the rule parameters to be `null` to indicate any color, or to use Color.any to support that, although I think it's confusing to have `any` in the enum with other colors... Anyway, I digress. The point is, if you want to implement that, you have to do that only in one place without having to copy it 16 times.

You could abstract this away a bit further by making such a rule a separate object, which you can put in a list or dictionary, but for a definition like this, it doesn't make it *that* much more readable, although it does add some benefits of testibility, as well as the possibility to add different kinds of rules, without messing up your clean list again.

Comment: This is a great answer. I want to add that if the mappings are already made in Excel, it's pretty easy to _generate_ this map using any programming language. That is, read the excel file as input, and have this disctionary as the output. Food for though anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Dictionary<T>`, for instance:

```
static Dictionary<Tuple<Shape, Color, Material>, Action> s_Actions = new
  Dictionary<Tuple<Shape, Color, Material>, Action>() {
    {Tuple.Create(Shape.square, Color.blue, Material.glass), () => { ... } },
     ...  
    {Tuple.Create(Shape.any, Color.red, Material.metal), () => { ... } },
     ...
  };

private static void RunAction(MyItem item) {
  Action action;

  // Either exact match or match with Any 
  if (!s_Actions.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(item.ItemShape, item.ItemColor, item.ItemMaterial), 
                             out action))
    action = s_Actions.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Key.Item1 == Color.any &&
                                              pair.Key.Item2 == item.ItemColor &&
                                              pair.Key.Item3 == item.ItemMaterial) 

  // Execute action if it's found
  if (action != null) 
    action();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void RunAction((Shape shape, Color color, Material material) item)
{
    switch(item)
    {
        case var i1 when i1.color == Color.red && i1.shape == Shape.square:
        case var i2 when i2.color == Color.blue:
            // Do action...
            break;
        case var i1 when i1.shape == Shape.trangle && i1.material == Material.metal:
            // Do action...
            break;
        default:
            // Do action...
            break;
    }
}
```

This solution uses [Value Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples), but primarily uses C#7 [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) in switch statements.

I don't think it totally solves your problem cleanly, but I think the multi-line cases gives you extra readability over the if statement approach and it's easy to implement.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I know from hard-learned experience that a slightly longer list is in the end easier to maintain than 'smart' nested logic.